# ZF2 Is there a shorter/cleaner way to get the TableGateway classes in a controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Recently I made my first ZF2 application. I was walking through the code to see if I could make the code somewhat cleaner. Then I noticed that my controller classes have a huge block of code that supplies the controller of the TableGateway classes it needs. And I wondered is there a shorter/cleaner way to do this? It just seems silly that half of my controller class is dedicated to this simple task of fetching some TableGateWay classes.

```
protected $appointmentTable;
protected $customerTable;
protected $serviceTable;
protected $locationTable;
// ... some action methods that actually do the work.
public function getAppointmentTable()
{
    if (!$this->appointmentTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->appointmentTable = $sm->get('Appointment\Model\AppointmentTable');
    }
    return $this->appointmentTable;
}

public function getServiceTable()
{
    if (!$this->serviceTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->serviceTable = $sm->get('Appointment\Model\ServiceTable');
    }
    return $this->serviceTable;
}

public function getLocationTable()
{
    if (!$this->locationTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->locationTable = $sm->get('Appointment\Model\LocationTable');
    }
    return $this->locationTable;
}

public function getCustomerTable()
{
    if (!$this->customerTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->customerTable = $sm->get('Customer\Model\CustomerTable');
    }
    return $this->customerTable;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your Controllers should ideally be set up is through the means of proper(!) dependency injection. In Zend Framework 2 you have two main ways to declare controllers within the `ControllerManager`. The first one being `invokables` for controllers who have no dependencies and the second one being `factories` for controllers who have dependencies.

Any `TableGateway` always **is a dependency**. To my experience there are no controllers who are invokables at all :P

There's two ways to set up controller factories.

1. `Module.php` using `getControllerConfig()`
2. Under the `controllers[factories]` key in your `module.config.php` using Factory-Classes

For simplicity I'll choose the first approach now:

```
public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'My\Foo\Controller' => function ($cpm) {
                //@var $cpm \Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager
                $serviceLocator = $cpm->getServiceLocator();
                $tableGateway   = $serviceLocator->get('My\Table\Gateway');

                return new \My\Foo\Controller($tableGateway);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

With this, all that's left is for you to modify your controller and have it pass the respective tablegateway inside its constructor:

```
class Controller
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(\My\Table\Gateway $tg)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tg;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'entries' => $this->tableGateway->select()
        ));
    }
}
```

And that's all there is to it. It's all about proper dependency injection that makes your life ultimately so much easier.

Obviously this example only covers one table, but you can do the same just passing more tables through the constructor. That is: only if you really need ALL TableGateways in there (which sounds a bit fishy) ;)

Comment: Great approach. Maybe even passing the tg's through an array to the constructor so only one param is needed?

Comment: Well, since Database abstraction sits in a controller, is breaks the DiP

Comment: Nope floris, that wouldn't be good. Remember that you want to have "clean code". One should be able to tell with just one look what your class is all about. If you pass a random array, no one knows what will be the classes injected. If however you inject specific classes (and even better, typehint them) then one knows exactly what's going on.

Comment: @djay Obviously it'd even be better to have only Services injected into your controller who then internally act with the tablegateway(s) injected to them. But it's not the best thing to make things overly complicated for users not knowing the basics of DI at all ;) step by step into the right direction most often works better.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just simplify the process in another method? I'm not aware of this function in Zend2, but still, if there is no method on framework level, you can write your own simplified method

My test so far:

```
public function setTable($method) {
    $method = lcfirst(str_replace("get", "", $method));
    $this->$method = 'Apointment\Model\\'.ucfirst($method);
    return $this->$method;
}

public function getLocationTable() {
    $this->setTable(__FUNCTION__);
    var_dump(get_object_vars($this));
}
```

Outputs:

```
array (size=1)
  'locationTable' => string 'Apointment\Model\LocationTable' (length=30)
```

So you can change `setTable()` method to use your `set()` proxy:

```
public function setTable($method) {
    $method = lcfirst(str_replace("get", "", $method));
    if (!$this->$method) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->$method = $sm->get('Apointment\Model\\'.ucfirst($method));
    }
    return $this->$method;
}

public function getLocationTable() {
    return $this->setTable(__FUNCTION__);
}

public function getServiceTable() {
    return $this->setTable(__FUNCTION__);
}
```

Or you can get all your tables in array, iterate through it and pass the name to your `setTable()` method, which will set inner properties.

---

My string test (because I don't have ZF2 right here, and testing if the proper string which you are passing to the `set()` proxy is built:

```
class Tables {

    public function setTable($method) {
        $method = lcfirst(str_replace("get", "", $method));
        $this->$method = 'Apointment\Model\\'.ucfirst($method);
            /*if (!$this->$method) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->$method = $sm->get('Apointment\Model\\'.ucfirst($method));
            }*/
        return $this->$method;
    }

    public function getLocationTable() {
        return $this->locationTable;
    }

    public function getServiceTable() {
        return $this->serviceTable;
    }

    public function getAppointmentTable() {
        return $this->appointmentTable;
    }

    public function setAllTables() {
        foreach (get_class_methods(__CLASS__) as $method) {
            if (strpos($method, 'get')!== false && strpos($method, 'Table')!==false)
                $this->setTable($method);
        }
    }
}

$tables = new Tables();
$tables->setAllTables();
var_dump(get_object_vars(($tables)));
```

Outputs:

```
array (size=3)
  'locationTable' => string 'Apointment\Model\LocationTable' (length=30)
  'serviceTable' => string 'Apointment\Model\ServiceTable' (length=29)
  'appointmentTable' => string 'Apointment\Model\AppointmentTable' (length=33)
```

Now all your `get____Table()` methods are valid getters. E.g.:

```
var_dump($tables->getServiceTable());
```

returns

```
string 'Apointment\Model\ServiceTable' (length=29)
```