# Zend Framework 2 getControllerConfig vs getConfig

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am listening to this talk here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vp7y65rnN98

At the 44:00  `Module.php::getConfig()` vs `Module.php::getControllerConfig()`

looking at an example module like ZFCampuses `zf-apigility-admin` module ...

I see BOTH `config/module.config.php` and `Module.php::getControllerConfig()` defining Controller Factories.

**zf-apigility/config/module.config.php**

```
'controllers' => array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\HttpBasicAuthentication' => 'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\Authentication',
        'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\HttpDigestAuthentication' => 'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\Authentication',
        'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\OAuth2Authentication' => 'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\Authentication',
    ),
    'invokables' => array(
        'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\App' => 'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\AppController',
        'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\CacheEnabled' => 'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\CacheEnabledController',
        'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\FsPermissions' => 'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\FsPermissionsController',
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\Documentation' => 'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\DocumentationControllerFactory',
        'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\Filters' => 'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\FiltersControllerFactory',
        'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\Hydrators' => 'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\HydratorsControllerFactory',
        'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\Validators' => 'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\ValidatorsControllerFactory',
        'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\InputFilter' => 'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\InputFilterControllerFactory',
    ),
),
```

**zf-apigility/Module.php**

```
 public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return array('factories' => array(
            'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\Authentication' => function ($controllers) {
                $services = $controllers->getServiceLocator();
                $model    = $services->get('ZF\Apigility\Admin\Model\AuthenticationModel');
                return new Controller\AuthenticationController($model);
            },
            'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\Authorization' => function ($controllers) {
                $services = $controllers->getServiceLocator();
                $factory  = $services->get('ZF\Apigility\Admin\Model\AuthorizationModelFactory');
                return new Controller\AuthorizationController($factory);
            },
            'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\Config' => function ($controllers) {
                $services = $controllers->getServiceLocator();
                return new Controller\ConfigController($services->get('ZF\Configuration\ConfigResource'));
            },
            'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\ModuleConfig' => function ($controllers) {
                $services = $controllers->getServiceLocator();
                return new Controller\ModuleConfigController($services->get('ZF\Configuration\ConfigResourceFactory'));
            },
            'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\ModuleCreation' => function ($controllers) {
                $services = $controllers->getServiceLocator();
                $model    = $services->get('ZF\Apigility\Admin\Model\ModuleModel');
                return new Controller\ModuleCreationController($model);
            },
            'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\Source' => function ($controllers) {
                $services = $controllers->getServiceLocator();
                $model    = $services->get('ZF\Apigility\Admin\Model\ModuleModel');
                return new Controller\SourceController($model);
            },
            'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Controller\Versioning' => function ($controllers) {
                $services = $controllers->getServiceLocator();
                $factory  = $services->get('ZF\Apigility\Admin\Model\VersioningModelFactory');
                return new Controller\VersioningController($factory);
            },
        ));
    }
```

My question is, why is this doubling up occurring here?  What am I missing about the usage of `Module.php::getControllerConfig()` vs merely listing the Factories in `Module.config.php` ?

Edit : I think I found the answer to my question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22374072/389976

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll see that all the factories defined in `Module.php` use closures (AKA anonymous functions). The convention is for all config to go into `module.config.php` except for the closures.

ZF has built-in functionality (disabled by default) to cache the merged config files, but it can't do that if the config file contains closures, as these cannot be serialized, and thus are not cacheable. By keeping them separate you can enable config caching, which improves performance.

**Edit**: Perhaps we're talking at crossed purposes a little here. My answer above hopefully explains why the closures from `Module.php` shouldn't be moved to the module config file. You could of course create factory *classes* for each of the closures defined, and then list those in the module config. Some would consider this best practice (personally I rarely do this). At this point it's a trade off between ease of development and performance. It's much more convenient to create a four line closure than create a whole new class.

Comment: Okay that's good then because I have everything right now in the module.config.php ... which was confusing me seeing this alternative loading pattern.

So I should leave things in the module.config.php if/when I enable caching, and want my module to cache.

Comment: It's worth getting into the habit of separating it, it doesn't take any longer and might save you time in the future. Also consider if you wanted to release a module for other people to use - if you have closures in config files you might be breaking their caching.

Comment: Where can i explore the pluses minuses more deeply... I thought id want as much cached as possible..

Comment: I've added a bit to my answer - hopefully that's a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I'm still learning ZF2 from scratch and this whole system is very obscure.  Lack of documentation that I 'get' makes it painful at times.

Is there a book or tutorial in addition to the straight docs you recommend for the inner workings of ZF2 and or Apigility?

Comment: as to your edit, I would wonder which will run faster for me.. only one way to test is write both and run them side by side?